# How can I add a model/class from one package to the other class/model present in other package in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I have a block (submodel)`Submodel_A` in a model `Model_AA` present in a package `Package_A`. I would like to add `Submodel_A` into another model `Model_AB`, which is present in package `Package_B`.

I tried copying the components or the code and pasting it where I wanted, but did not work. A generic solution would be great.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://book.xogeny.com/components/packages/

Answer (score 1):

I'm  not sure if i got your point. But neither

- right click on `Submodel_A` (Package Browser) -> `Duplicate Class...`

nor

- right click on `Submodel_A` (Package Browser) -> `Rename...` 
  (you can use this option to move a model and to ensure that all references to the model will be updated)

solve your problem?